# Check the presence of a number after nth digit and then filter your dataframe in Python

Tags: python

My data consists of a date column, which looks like  -

| Date |
| --- |
| 20221201 |
| 20221202 |
| 20221203 |
| 20221101 |
| 20221102 |

I need to filter the dataframe only for the month of december, I tried something like -

`df = df[df['Date'][4:6] == 12]`

its not working

Comment: did you try `== "12"`

Comment: @treuss I tried, it gives error -  Unalignable boolean series ...indexer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert strings into actual dates, then extract month and check if it is equal to desired following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["20221201","20221202","20221203","20221101","20221102"]})
df["Date_object"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],format="%Y%m%d")
df2 = df[df["Date_object"].dt.month==12]
print(df2)
```

gives output

```
       Date Date_object
0  20221201  2022-12-01
1  20221202  2022-12-02
2  20221203  2022-12-03
```

Answer (score 0):

See @Daweo's answer for the clean way to do this.

If you actually want to 'slice' an integer (not recommended with dates), you can use a floor division (`//`) in combination with the modulus (`%`).

```py
df = df[(df['Date'] // 100) % 100 == 12]
```

Explanation:
`// 100` 'removes' the last two digits while `% 100` only keeps the last two digits.

```py
20221201 // 100 = 202212
202212 % 100 = 12
```